# In the case where ⊕ is involved as a composite system M1 ⊕ M2, what kind of equation does ⊕ denote?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, kronecker-product

I am reading about relations between equations using kronecker products as well as the use of ⊕ in situations such as M1 ⊕ M2, M ⊕ N, S ⊕ S, S⊕S⊕…n and others besides. In these papers they are called composite systems.

I understand that in a kronecker product a multiplication is performed on each element of the first matrix by every element in the second and it forms a block matrix of the two systems. Such as that Amxn ⊗ Bpxq is the matrix pm x nq. With situations such as a11 x b11, a11xb12, etc...

But what kind of equation is the followed out by the ⊕ symbol in the case of the above equations?

Comment: It probably denotes a [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Direct_sum). It also might denote a [Kronecker sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Relations_to_other_matrix_operations).

Comment: What kind of things are $M_1,M_2, M, N, S$?  Typically $\oplus$ denotes a direct sum of groups, rings, vector spaces, or other compatible algebraic structures.  It is important to the meaning of $\oplus$ to know what its object of application is.

Comment: Almost certainly vector spaces. It is being used in a theoretical extension of Von Neumann's conception of a universal Constructor. M usually denotes some information medium or S some substrate. On occasion E is used to denote the environment of some substrate.

Comment: If this is in a physics context, then this is in reference to addition of angular momentum. What's going on there is that one forms a composite system by tensoring two irreps together, obtaining a reducible representation which can be decomposed as the direct sum of two other irreps.

Comment: If one is working with matrices directly, though, one cute identity is this: $\exp(A)\otimes \exp(B)=\exp(A\oplus B)$ where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product and $\oplus$ is the Kronecker sum.

Answer (score 1):

You are working in the category of vector spaces over some field $k$. Let us denote that category by $C$.

If $M,N\in \text{obj}(C)$ then $M\oplus N$ denotes the direct sum of spaces and $M\otimes N$ denotes the tensor product of two spaces. These are both objects of this category.

Suppose now that you have two morphisms $f_1:M_1\to N_1$ and $f_2:M_2\to N_2$. The direct sum will give you the direct sum of morphisms $f_1\oplus f_2:(M_1\oplus M_2)\to (N_1\oplus N_2)$ and the tensor product will give a morphism $f_1\otimes f_2:(M_1\otimes M_2)\to (N_1\otimes N_2)$.

Since $f_1\oplus f_2$ and $f_1\otimes f_2$ are morphisms in the category $C$ it means they can be represented by matrix multiplication. If $A$ is the matrix that represents $f_1$ and $B$ is the matrix that represents $f_2$ then the "direct sum of matrices" is just the corresponding matrix for $f_1\oplus f_2$ which is formed by sticking the two matrices diagonally. Likewise for $f_1\otimes f_2$ you get the "Kronecker product" for the two matrices.